# How to manipulate properties of the object prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-5, function-constructor

I'm trying to do the following:

```
function SomeFunctionConstructor() {
   this.someMainVariable = "someValue";
   this.manipulatePrototype = () => {
     this.someProtoVariable = "some new value";
   }
}

SomeFunctionConstructor.prototype.someProtoVariable = "Some proto value";


var someInstance = new SomeFunctionConstructor();
```

Now, if I `console.log(someInstance)`, it prints:

```
{
  someMainVariable: 'someValue',
  manipulatePrototype: [Function] 
}
```

And now, when I do `someInstance.manipulatePrototype()` and then `console.log(someInstance)`, it prints:

```
{
  someMainVariable: 'someValue',
  manipulatePrototype: [Function],
  someProtoVariable: 'some new value' 
}
```

Why does it create a new `someProtoVariable` directly on the instance instead of updating the `someProtoVariable` on the prototype? :(

Comment: Because that's how JavaScript object property assignment always works. It's a fundamental part of the language design. Things would be very weird if it were to work differently.

Comment: `this` in in manipulatePrototype is exactly the same as `this` outside of it

Comment: @Pointy Well, as far as I know when we access a property on an object, it first checks if there is a direct property on that object, if not, looks for the property in the prototype chain. If it finds one in the prototype chain it would do the operation on that, and if it couldn't, would create a new property directly on the object. Isn't it?

Comment: That's when it's *getting* a property value. When the property reference is on the left side of any assignment operator, it *always* sets the property directly on the target object.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for your answer but how can you say that? Can you provide me some reference? :)

Comment: Well you're seeing it happen in the code you're working with, right? Isn't your own experience evidence enough? It's in the language spec but that's extremely complicated reading.

Comment: Note that there is a big exception to that rule: if there is a setter function for the property anywhere in the prototype chain, then that *will* be used to perform the property value assignment.

Comment: [Here is a fairly concise description of how things work.](http://2ality.com/2012/08/property-definition-assignment.html)

Comment: @Pointy Okay, I get it. But do you happen to know how can we update prototype property instead of creating a new direct property as happening in my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178372/discussion-between-utkarshpramodgupta-and-pointy).

Comment: You can just write `Object.getPrototypeOf(someInstance).propertyName = value;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dude! It worked. :-D Do you mind writing an answer (not comment) so that I can approve it? :) @Pointy

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to modify a property on an object's prototype, you can either refer to the prototype directly via the constructor:

```
SomeConstructor.prototype.property = newValue;
```

or use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` on an instance:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(someInstance).property = newValue;
```

Now, in general things can get kind-of complicated, because an instance may have more than one object in its prototype chain. Exactly what you might want in such a case is up to your application.

Note that changing the property value on the prototype will have the effect of making the property have the new value on all instances.

You could add a `setter` function to the prototype to do this automatically:

```
Object.defineProperty(SomeConstructor.prototype, "property", {
  value: someInitialValue,
  set: function(value) {
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this)["@property"] = value;
  },
  get: function() {
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(this)["@property"];
  }
});
```

That uses another prototype property called "@property" (could be any name, or better yet a `Symbol` instance) to store the apparent value of "property". With that,

```
someInstance.property = newValue;
```

would make a call to the setter function and update the "@property" value on the prototype.

Comment: Note that this would be a *somewhat* strange thing to do, and a system that made extensive use of this strategy might exhibit lots of unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are confusing between an instance and the prototype .  and instance cant over the object prototype by design. if this would happens then every instance will be able to destroy the prototype chain and effect all other instances that are built from this prototype

if you print someInstance.someProtoVariable without calling manipulatePrototype then you will get the old value.

and after you will get the new value .
 this.someProtoVariable did override the default value for the instance  but didn`t override the prototype  itself

you can read more about prototype here 
[Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)